# cursor.getstring() is getting the wrong field in the database

Tags: java, android, database

So this  is my code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id)
{
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

    int _id = cursor.getInt(0);
    String _recipe = cursor.getString(1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Luzon1Activity.this,RecipeInstruction.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", _id);
    intent.putExtra("recipe", _recipe);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is my code for the next activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recipeinstruction);

    dbHelper = new Dbadapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();
    bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        id = extras.getInt("id");   
        recipe = extras.getString("recipe");
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, id+"\n"+recipe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    bg.setBackgroundResource(getImageId(this, recipe));
}
```

My problem is on this part:  `String _recipe = cursor.getString(1)`.
It always gives me the wrong data. I tried to change the number but still it gives me the wrong data.

This is my database:

```
package com.pinoycookbook;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class Dbadapter
{
    public static final String ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String NAME = "foodname";
    public static final String ORIGIN = "origin";

    public static final String RECIPE = "recipe";

    public static final String CATEGORY = "category";

    private static final String TAG = "Dbadapter";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PinoyCookbook.sqlite";
    public static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Food";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                NAME + " TEXT," +
                RECIPE + " TEXT," +
                ORIGIN + " TEXT," + 
                CATEGORY+ " TEXT,"+
                " UNIQUE (" + ROWID +"));";

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public Dbadapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public Dbadapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    public long createData(String foodname, String recipe, String origin,  int i) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(NAME, foodname);
        initialValues.put(RECIPE, recipe);
        initialValues.put(ORIGIN, origin);

        initialValues.put(CATEGORY, i);

        return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteAllData() {
        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;
    }

    public void insertData() {
        createData("Adobong Manok","adobongmanok","Manila",1);
        createData("Lechon","lechon","Cebu",2);
        createData("Crispy Pata","crispypata","Cebu",2);
        createData("Bulalo","bulalo","Batangas",1);
        createData("Taba ng Talangka Rice","talangkarice","Roxas",2);
        createData("Arroz Caldo","arrozcaldo","Roxas",2);
        createData("Sinigang","sinigang","Manila",1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So i recommend you to use [`getColumnIndex()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) method rather than hardcode it.

```
String _recipe = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Dbadapter.RECIPE));
```

It will ensure that you will get always right field. And if it still get wrong data problem is in query not in `Cursor`

**Note:** An usage of static fields that hold column names is always the best practise.

### Update:

> I've tried it before and it gives me this error:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'recipe' does not exist

You need to find out your actual table structure. Try to perform this statement:

```
PRAGMA table_info(Dbadapter.SQLITE_TABLE);
```

What says docs([source](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info)):

> This pragma returns one row for each column in the named table.
>   Columns in the result set include the column name, data type, whether
>   or not the column can be NULL, and the default value for the column.
>   The "pk" column in the result set is zero for columns that are not
>   part of the primary key, and is the index of the column in the primary
>   key for columns that are part of the primary key.

### Example:

Here i created for you method for getting tableinfo via `PRAGMA`:

```
public String getTableInfo() {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("");
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "pragma table_info(" + Dbadapter.SQLITE_TABLE + ")";
        c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                b.append("Col:" + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) + " ");                     
                b.append(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("type")));
                b.append("\n");
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
    finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be something like this:

```
Column: type text
Column: date text
```

Only for imagination i will give you screen:

[image: Pragram Android Example Screenshot]

Comment: i've tried it before and it gives me this error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'recipe' does not exist

Comment: @KempDomalanta it's not possible, you are created it in onCreate() method `RECIPE + " TEXT," `.

Comment: @KempDomalanta try to use `PRAGMA table_info(yourtablename);`

Comment: where will i put it? sorry, im still learning and new to android.

Comment: i've extracted a database before and it contains recipe field.  i dont know why it gives me that error. thanks for the time.  i'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

you can try it this way:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recipe"));
```

it returns you the correct index and as result the correct value.