# Application did not close cursor, despite getting closed

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an SQLite database in my Android Application.  When I do one operation I always get a Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed.  Here is the method:

```
public String getKey(){
    net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(Login.authPass);
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + STABLE;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); //This is the line that throws the exception
    String s = cursor.getString(1);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return s;
}
```

It is really frustrating, because I am going to close the Cursor, it just throws an exception before it even gets there.  Also I don't get how anything I'm doing on this line is considered finalizing the cursor.  Thank you.

Edited to add Logcat:

02-24 12:28:26.522  12756-12765/com.itsmr.dre2k14 E/Cursor﹕ Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.itsmr.dre2k14/databases/keys.db, table = null, query = SELECT  * FROM keys
    net.sqlcipher.database.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCursor.(SQLiteCursor.java:217)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1447)
            at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1416)
            at com.itsmr.dre_android_clean.KeyTable.getKey(KeyTable.java:41)
            at com.itsmr.dre_android_clean.Login.noConnectValidate(Login.java:218)
            at com.itsmr.dre_android_clean.Login.connect(Login.java:97)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: include logcat for the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should call moveToFirst() to move the cursor to the first row in the database.

Also, just making sure that this is what you intended, calling `cursor.getString(1);` will get the second column in the current row, since it is zero based.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)

Also, best practice is to make sure that a cursor is not null before you use it, also use try/catch for database operations.

```
public String getKey(){
 String s = null;

 try{
  net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(Login.authPass);
  String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + STABLE;
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
  if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    s = cursor.getString(1);
  }

 } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("MyApp", ex.getMessage());
 } finally
 {
    if (cursor != null) {
       cursor.close();

    }
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }

 }

return s;
}
```

This post might be helpful too:
[cursor.getstring() is getting the wrong field in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680853/cursor-getstring-is-getting-the-wrong-field-in-the-database/15680956#15680956)